# Querying mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of emails in MongoDB with a field containing an array of json.

How can knowing the sender and the receiver, how can I find all the emails exchanged between the two people ? I need to do something like

`db.email.find({"from": i.st20@gmail.com", "tos":"ron@gmail.com")`

but I cant find the right way to write this query :(

```
> db.emails.findOne()
{

    "from" : {
        "real_name" : "it",
        "address" : "i.st20@gmail.com"
    },
    "tos" : [
        {
            "real_name" : null,
            "address" : "ron@gmail.com"
        }
    ],

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "from.address" and "tos.address":

```
db.emails.find({"from.address" : "i.st20@gmail.com", "tos.address" : "ron@gmail.com"})
```

Comment: Quick link to the documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-fields-of-a-subdocument

Answer (score 3):

Each field is considered as a json, we can precise the expected value through a "." :

```
db.emails.find({"tos.address" : "ron@gmail.com", "from.address":"i.st20@gmail.com"})
```

Answer (score 1):

From and To are objects and data inside them can be accessed through a `.` operator.
So the query will be:

```
db.emails.find({"from.address" : "i.st20@gmail.com", "tos.address" : "ron@gmail.com"}).
```